# How to use .MoveRotation, .rotation, .MovePosition and .position properly on Rigidbody2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a 'space shooter'-type game for learning purposes. I have trouble with moving the spaceship with Rigidbody2D.

I have already tried running the commands in Update(), FixedUpdate() and using exclusively the Rigidbody2D component (omitting the use of Transform entirely). I also tried marking the Rigidbody2D as both Dynamic and Kinematic, and changed the Simulated property. Nothing worked.

This is my current (not working) code:

```
Rigidbody2D rb;

void Start()
{
   rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
        rb.MoveRotation(angularSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
        rb.MoveRotation(-angularSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    rb.MovePosition(Vector2.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

I expected this code to make the spaceship turn left when I press the 'Q' key, turn right, when I press the 'E' key and always move forward. The actual result is that the spaceship doesn't move and instead of rotating only jitters when either the key 'Q' or 'E' is pressed (it rotates a single step right or left and then no longer responds to input). The code doesn't generate any error messages nor any warnings and doesn't throw any exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Rigidbody2D.MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.MovePosition.html) and [`Rigidbody2D.MoveRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.MoveRotation.html) both expect **absolute** parameters of the final rotation/position you expect them to move to.

For `MovePosition` you did it correct but for the `MoveRotation` you are passing in only the relative rotation change but forgot to add it to the current rotation.

---

It should rather be

```
void FixedUpdate(
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
        rb.MoveRotation(rb.rotation + angularSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
        rb.MoveRotation(rb.rotation + -angularSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    rb.MovePosition(transform.position + Vector3.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I just realised that. It seems like you have to read the docs VERY carefully.

Comment: @YanB. and look at the examples ;) They often explain it better than the doc texts themselves